# Confused about how to set up bounds for a triple integral for a cone

Tags: integration, divergence-operator

What would be the bounds for the triple integral over the surface of a cone,
$$x^2+y^2 \leq z^2 $$ where $$0 \leq z \leq a$$

My first guess is to use polar coordinates for $x$ and $y$:
$$x=rcos(\theta)$$
$$y=rsin(\theta)$$

I am unsure about what to use for $z$, and then I am unsure what the bounds of integration are for $x$ and $y$ when I go to set up my triple integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $r^2\le z^2$, thus $0\le r\le z$. On the other hand $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$, therefore
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{z}r\,\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}\theta=\frac 13 a^3 \pi$$

Comment: If my function is $F=[x^2,y^2,z^2]$, then what would be the function I am integrating?  I take the partials and get $2x+2y+2z$, so is it $2rcos(\theta)+2rsin(\theta)+2z$?

Comment: Apply Divergence theorem . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^a\int_0^{z}\int_0^{2\pi}r\mathrm d\theta\mathrm dr\mathrm dz=\frac{1}{3}\pi a^3$$

One way to see this is consider a section of the cone at certain heigh z. Its area is $\pi z^2$. Then you simply have to integrate it between $0$ and $a$. The two inner integrals give you the area, the third, the volume.